# Find sub-sequence of events from a stream of events

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am giving a miniature version of my issue below

I have 2 different sensors sending 1/0 values as a stream. I am able to consume the stream using Kafka and bring it to spark for processing. Please note a sample stream I have given below.

Time     -------------->         1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

Sensor Name  -->     A  **A B** B   B   B   **A B** A   A

Sensor Value --->   1   **0 1** 0   1   0   **0 1** 1   0

I want to identify a sub sequence pattern occurring in this stream. For eg- if A =0 and the very next value (based on time) in the stream is B =1 then I want to push an alert. In the example above I have highlighted 2 places – where I want to give an alert.   In general it will be like

> “If a set of sensor-event combination happens within a time interval,
>   raise an alert”.

I am new to spark and don’t know Scala. I am currently doing my coding using python.

My actual problem contains more sensors and each sensor can have different value combinations. Meaning my subsequence and event stream

I have tried Couple of options without success

- Window Functions – Can be useful for moving avgs cumulative sums
  etc. not for this usecase
- Bring spark Dataframes /RDDs to local python structure like list
  and panda Dataframes and do sub-sequencing – it take lots of
  shuffles and spark event streams queued after some iterations
- UpdateStatewithKey – Tried couple of ways and not able to understand
  fully how this works and whether this is applicable for    this use
  case.

Comment: did you manage to find the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for a solution to this question can use my solution:

1- To keep them connected, you need to gather events with collect_list.

2- It's best to sort your event on the collect_list, but be cautious because it arranges data by the first column, so it's important to put the DateTime in that column.

3- I dropped DateTime from collect_list, as an example.

4- Finally, you should contact all elements to explore it with string functions like contain to find your subsequence.

```
.agg(expr("array_join(TRANSFORM(array_sort(collect_list((Time , Sensor Value))), a -> a.Time ),'')")as "MySequence")
```

after this agg function, you can use any regular expression or string function to detect your pattern.

check this link for more information about collect_list:
[collect list](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-collect-list-and-collect-set-functions/)
check this link for more information about sorting a collect_list:
[sort a collect list](https://keestalkstech.com/2019/09/sorting-an-array-of-a-complex-data-type-in-spark/)